# Friendly url html with folder language

Tags: html, url

I was wondering how this site https://www.jrsa.com.ar/ works with friendly URLS and languaje selector.
For example, if you put https://www.jrsa.com.ar/es https://www.jrsa.com.ar/es/es is the same result, the same page. In the browser if you write https://www.jrsa.com.ar/servicios is the same if you write http://www.jrsa.com.ar/es/ex/servicios.
In the browser if you type www.jrsa.com.ar/folder/folder/folder/servicios is the same as www.jrsa.com.ar/servicios. I can´t understand how you can add folders and getting the same page.

Can some help me to find to achieve this? I only have this htaccess

```
 # Activar RewriteEngine
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Mi test URL is: http://clients.devilleartstudios.com/jrsa

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suspect their content is stored in a CMS database that supports localized content. It is not *feasible* to do this with a manually-managed static website because you'll need to  recreate common HTML structure (like navigation, global content, etc) in every page. If you really want to accomplish this with a static website then consider using a system like Jekyll: https://jekyllrb.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, the site was build in php. So, this crazy thing about ad aleatory www.jrsa.com.ar/folder/folder/folder is the same as www.jrsa.com.ar. I still thinking that it´s something in the htaccess.